# MySQL, equal or not equal?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am a bit puzzled to see this on MySQL

```
SELECT 1='1x';
```

gives me 1

Whereas

```
SELECT 1='2x';
```

gives me 0 (as expected)

When doing a binary compare

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS BINARY)=CAST('1x' AS BINARY);
```

it gives me 0 (also as expected)

Question: How can I stop MySQL from behaving like this? I want '=' to act as 100% binary equal. I don't want MySQL to assume or guess what I might wanted to compare.

Comment: Don't put the values in as strings:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-value-literals.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing strings and numbers then MySQL automatically makes a conversion.

So the string gets converted to a number and it starts from left to right and tries to make a number from it.

So

```
'1x' => 1
'x1' => 0 //because it does not start with a number on the left
```

You can't change that behaviour. And you should not compare different data types anyway. So it is your fault :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I was not aware of this. It's the first time I have to compare string to integer values as it is defined by the database schema. So am I on the safe side by casting both values as binary? Or are there still any caveats I might have to consider.

Comment: Comparing `1='1x'` is simply wrong. If you know there is a string on one side then compare with a string on the other side. `'1x'='1x'`